# Using boost::accumulators::statistics to find median of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

I have a 1-D array of large size computed in MATLAB. I need to find the median of this array. I want to use the boost c++ library for this purpose as it has implementation for computing median using P-square Algorithm which works efficiently for large sized arrays. Below is the code which pushes 5 numbers one by one and finds the median using boost library. I want to change this code so that I can pass an array as an argument and find the median of that array. The size of array is huge so I cannot use 'for loop' for pushing each element in accumulator set.

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main() {   
 accumulator_set<double, features<tag::mean, tag::median> > acc;  

 acc(8);   
 acc(9);   
 acc(10);   
 acc(11);   
 acc(12);   
 //double arr[3] = {1,2,3};   
 //acc(arr);   
 std::cout << mean(acc) << '\n';   
 std::cout << median(acc) << '\n'; 
}
```

I did find some resources asking to use vectors but I did not understand. A working example where a small array is passed as an argument and then median is found using boost c++ library would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply iterate:

```
for (auto d : arr)
    acc(d);
```

Or use the algorithm:

```
for_each(begin(arr), end(arr), ref(acc));
```

> Note: use `std::ref(acc)` to avoid passing by value!

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a7cab2809b371cd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::accumulators;

int main() {
    accumulator_set<double, features<tag::mean, tag::median> > acc;

    double arr[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    for (auto d : arr)
        acc(d);

    using namespace std;
    for_each(begin(arr), end(arr), ref(acc));

    std::cout << mean(acc) << '\n';
    std::cout << median(acc) << '\n';
}
```

### PS:

If you insist to have the function interface:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8240a4c1ae94c5e)</kbd>**

```
template <typename Accum, typename Range>
void do_sample(Accum& accum, Range const& range) {
    using namespace std;
    for_each(begin(range), end(range), std::ref(accum));
}
```

(works for vectors or any other range as well). Prints:

```
2
3
```

Comment: Added more explanation and a version with a function-call interface: [`do_sample`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8240a4c1ae94c5e)

Comment: @ChrisChiasson Good question, yes, and that's what you'd get (statistically) with larger series. Boost Accumulators is geared to _large_ datasets with sampling but no full in-memory datasets. For this reason, they [implement the `median` in terms of the _single quantile estimation with the P² algorithm_](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.median).

Comment: It's a classical accuracy/memory tradeoff. If you don't need it, just sort an array and pick the middle. If you need it, be happy that you can sample gigabytes and still have reliable results without waiting a long time on a huge machine :)